# Passing instructions to windows phone application from console application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I was following this [fantastic tutorial](http://justinangel.net/#BlogPost=WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation). Which showed this bit of code to talk to my windows phone application by writing/reading to a file in the isolatedstore.

```
object ConManServer = WP7Device.GetType().GetField("mConmanServer", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(WP7Device);

FileDeployer f = (FileDeployer)typeof(FileDeployer).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)[0].Invoke(new object[] { ConManServer });

f.ReceiveFile(@"\Applications\Data\" + appID + @"\data\isolatedstore\Foo.txt", @"\Foo.txt");
```

However, I get a file access denied. Somebody commented that:

> unfortunately Microsoft has removed that feature from the final
>   release of the CoreCon API. So it's no longer possible to transfer
>   files from the device in this lovely, easy manner.

I am wondering what would be the alternative to pass instructions to my Windows Phone application from a Console Application?

Maybe using the `DevicePacketStream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mango (v7.1) version of the SDK included the Isolated Storage Explorer Tool to make it possible to read and write files from IsolatedStorage.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408(v=vs.92).aspx